# Ввод и вывод данных на консоль четных и нечетных чисел

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду, что можно переделать или добавить?

Задача:

> Создать программу, которая будет сообщать, является ли целое число, введённое пользователем, чётным или нечётным. Если пользователь введёт не целое число, то сообщать ему об ошибке.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []){
       int number;
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Введите челое число -> ");
          if(sr.hasNextInt()){
            number = sr.nextInt();
             if ((number % 2) == 0){
               System.out.print("Четное число " + number);
             }else{System.out.print("Не четное число " + number);}
        }else{System.out.print("Вы ввели не целое число");}
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем что-то добавлять?

Comment: Или можно как нить сократить код? "Nofate"

Comment: Может быть стоит прочесть в строку не целое число. Иначе, если ввод делать в цикле, до следующего целого не доберетесь (зациклитесь).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно чуток уменьшить количество кода с помощью тернарного оператора:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите челое число -> ");

        if(sr.hasNextInt()) {
            int number = sr.nextInt();
            String category = (number % 2) == 0 ? "Четное" : "Нечетное";

            System.out.println(category + " число: " + number);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не целое число");
        }
    }
}
```

И объявление переменной лучше вносить внутрь того блока, где она используется. А так все ок.

Comment: Спасибо!Ответ найден Тема закрыта!

Comment: Ну, уж если сокращать строчки

    int     n;
    if (sr.hasNextInt())
        System.out.println("Введено "+
            (((n=sr.nextInt()) % 2) == 0 ? "Четное": "Нечетное")+
            " число: "+n);
    else
        System.out.println("Не целое число: "+sr.next());